# Using CVOpenGLESTextureRef as a render target?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, ios5

I am trying to figure out how to use `CVOpenGLESTextureRef` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef` to replace using `glReadPixels`.
I understand how to use them to create a texture from incoming camera images as shown in the RosyWriter and CameraRipple demos. But I can't figure out how to use them to go the other way.

Comments in the header file for the function `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` give the following example:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, 
    pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height, 
    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
```

and this is all the information I can find. How do you use this?

Currently I am doing the following to create my offscreen Frame Buffer Object at the start of the app.

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &frameBufferHandle);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, frameBufferHandle);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorBufferHandle);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorBufferHandle);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorBufferHandle);
```

Then when I need to write it out to disk I bind it and call `glReadPixels`.

- How would I use `CVOpenGLESTextureRef` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef` instead of the above?
- How would I use it on the main render buffer, and not on an offscreen FBO?

Other information that may be pertinent:

- I am using OpenGL ES 1.1 on 2.0 capable devices (moving to 2.0 is not an option).
- I am already using `CVOpenGLESTextureRef` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef` to display the camera video image on screen.
- I am writing out to video using `CVPixelBufferRefs` and BRGA format.
- If I use the main renderbuffer I can call `glReadPixels` with `GL_BGRA_EXT`.
- If I use an offscreen FBO (for a smaller video size) I have to use RGBA format and do bit swizzling.

Comment: Are you sure this is bidirectional? I was under the impression from reading the headers that the above example was for feeding directly to the render buffer, not reading back from it.

Comment: No, I am not sure. It was the impression that I got. So, you are thinking that that the above example would be used to write the video frame as the background to renderbuffer? i.e your GL scene would be drawn directly on the video image which you could later present to the screen. I am still not sure how I would actually use that example if that is the case.

Comment: My interpretation of the above would be that you could use it to write an image directly to the renderbuffer, filling the frame. I'm not sure if you'd be able to layer content on this. I'm working on a framework that will use some of this, so I may need to give this a try. I agree that we need something faster than `glReadPixels()`, but I'm not sure that we've been given it yet.